# USB Serial and SPI with Teensy 4.0

Tags: arduino, usb, spi, teensy

My usecase requires me to send Computer (USB) -> Teensy 4.0 -> SPI -> Peripheral
I am attempting to send data over USB (potentially USB serial or is there any other way). My data transfer requirement is sending 40,16-bit data, 4000 times a second, which translates to around 2.56Mbits per second.

I plan to cache 1 second of data, which is 2560000 bits or 320 Kilobytes or 312.5 Kibibytes

I am looking for guidance regarding:

1. Caching mechanism (mutex), and 1024 bytes of RAM availability, parallelly transfer data from USB to Teensy 4.0 to SPI. i.e. Threading within Teensy / Arduino.
2. How to effectively transfer 320kb of data per second over USB to teensy 4.0?
3. Text-based serial transfer or hex bytes? Any links or articles.
4. Is there any other language to program Teensy 4.0 for this purpose that could be more effective than Arduino (TeensyDuino)?

Comment: I think you're going to find this rather difficult.  You could *try* using the ecosystem's built in USB-serial (baud rate is ignored) and making sure on the host OS side to pass well chosen buffer sizes (as a *guess* buffers a multiple of a packet size).  You would definitely want to use a binary transfer to avoid overhead.  It's possibly however that you'll need to implement a more optimal scheme at low level yourself on both sides.

Comment: If this is effectively a streaming need requiring bulk speed but not "agility" in the sense of questions and answers you might consider instead a USB-FIFO chip with SPI capability, eg FT2232H, Cypress FX2/FX3, etc or their more recent follow-ons.   Or you could perhaps move a larger portion of the task comprising both the PC's role and the SPI host to something like a Raspberry Pi (or its more robust equivalents).  You may also be able to "chop up" streaming SPI into individual register writes with a simple state machine in a CPLD.

Comment: You seem to have several related questions going back a few months including some experiments with lower-end USB-SPI FIFOs.  As such it would really help if you could "edit" this current question to better explain the overall project goal, what you are talking to and what the ultimate requirements are, what the flow of data looks like in terms of timing vs. any external events, etc, and what issues with past attempts put you onto this path instead.

Comment: @ChrisStratton, I am attempting to run AD5370 chip via a microcontroller/usb solution in which I can send signals to it at a fast rate. My ideal rate is 4k  (16-bit) samples / second / channel. I have POC'd it with FT232H, Raspberry Pi, and few other options. The closest has been FT232H, In which i could get 4k  (16-bit) samples per second per channel. But the chip seems to crash often. Theoretically FT232H has a SPI speed of 30 Mhz, AD5370 can work up to 50Mhz, But for my usecase all i need is a consistent 3.84 Mhz SPI.

Comment: If I optimize the data packets from USB to the Microcontroller, i can potentially transmit only 2.56 Mbits per second via USB to MC, then pad it up to 3.84 Mbit via SPI (channel address) to the AD5370 chip. All of these seems theoretically possible, but practically seems quite challenging. I have POCs running 20k samples per second for 1 channel. Which is the theoretical limit of AD5370. 

The next closest chip that seems to achieve the SPI speed is Teensy 4.0, but i still haven't figured out an optimal USB communication protocol from the computer to Teensy

Comment: With efficient software and buffering this may work at USB full speed, but it may be tricky; you want to think DMA, not really "threads".  I think Teensy has their own forums, or you can use more generic Kinetis, MBED, etc resources for the actual MCU involved.  One of the USB2 or USB3 FIFO IC's should easily have the speed; "crashing" sounds like it might be an electrical problem on the USB bus that could apply to any sort of solution depending on unlucky coincidence of factors.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Actually, for a T4.x a data rate of 300kB over the virtual serial port is not demanding at all.

I suggest to use a simple ring buffer (e.g. https://github.com/tonton81/Circular_Buffer) for storage of received data.

To achieve your data transfer requirement (1 block of 40 16bit words every 250µs) it might be best to send out one block of data in a timer ISR and invoke this ISR with 4kHz.

Here some prove of principle code showing how to achieve this:

```
    #include "SPI.h"
    #include "circular_buffer.h"
    
    Circular_Buffer<uint16_t, 16*1024> ringBuffer;  // adjust buffer size if necessary
    
    constexpr unsigned CS = 0;
    constexpr size_t blockSize = 40;
    
    void sendSPI()
    {
        if (ringBuffer.available() >= blockSize) // send only a complete data block
        {
            SPI.beginTransaction(SPISettings(4'000'000, MSBFIRST, SPI_MODE0));
            digitalWriteFast(CS, LOW); // assuming an active low chip select
            for (unsigned i = 0; i < blockSize; i++)
            {
                SPI.transfer16(ringBuffer.read()); // read one entry from the buffer and send it
            }
            digitalWriteFast(CS, HIGH);
            SPI.endTransaction();
        }
    }
    
    IntervalTimer spiTimer;
    
    void setup()
    {
        pinMode(CS, OUTPUT);
        SPI.begin();        
        spiTimer.begin(sendSPI, 1'000'000 / 4000); // transfer one block every 250µs
    }
    
    uint16_t oldDatum = -1; // error checking, we expect incrementing data from serial
    
    void loop()
    {
        while (Serial.available() && ringBuffer.available() < ringBuffer.capacity())
        {
            uint16_t datum;
            Serial.readBytes((char*)&datum, 2);
            ringBuffer.write(datum);
    
            uint16_t diff = datum - oldDatum;    
            if(diff != 1)
            {
                SerialUSB1.printf("Error @%04X\n", datum);
            }
            oldDatum = datum;
        }    
    }
```

As long as there is space availabe, the code copies received serial data into the ring buffer. The timer interrupt driven sending part reads a 40word block from the ring buffer and sends it to your device.

To check if any data is lost, the code checks the incoming bytes and prints out any error (data not incrementing) on the second serial connection.

I used the following simple c# application to test the firmware.

```
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {                                                       
            int bufSize = 2 * 64 * 1024;               // generate some dummy data (incrementing 16bit values)
            var data = new byte[bufSize];              // any buffer size would work. I chose 128kB to get a nice data wrap around for the simple error detection in the firmware
            for (int i = 0; i < bufSize / 2; i++)
            {
                var bytes = BitConverter.GetBytes(i);  // convert from uint16 to byte[4]
                data[i * 2] = bytes[0];
                data[i * 2 + 1] = bytes[1];
            }

            // Send out the data as quick as possible, the underlying algorithms will pause sending if the FW doesn't read the bytes from the stream. 
            // -> this is auto syncing the rate with the FW read rate. 
            using (var port = new SerialPort("COM11"))
            {
                port.Open();
                while (!Console.KeyAvailable)      // stop program on any key press
                {
                    port.Write(data, 0, bufSize);  // send out data, driver will pause if necessary
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Both, FW and SW work without issue here and I didn't observe any data loss. The underlying PC driver is smart enough to pause sending when the FW is not reading the data from the stream. Thus, you get a synchronization of the sending and  receiving data rate for free.

Here some measurement results for 4MHz SPI frequency:

[image]

Zoomed in:
[image]

And here a measurement with 32MHz SPI frequency (can't resolve details with my LA at this speed). But you can see that sending one block (80byte) is done in about 32µs.

[image]

Comment: this is exactly what i wanted "1 block of 40 16bit words every 250µs" via USB to teensy. Let me go through this in detail and hopefully i can understand what you said. I might get back to you with some clarifying questions. Thankyou again